# Slide edges in Blender when model is subdivided into quads

Tags: edges

I have the following mesh:
[image: My Mesh]

Now, I would like to move the green edges parallel in Blender to the red line. Normally I would slide the edges with <kbd>G</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, but this mesh is already divided into squares in this area. And when I merge the part of the mesh with <kbd>F</kbd>, I get strange results or the edges cannot be moved downwards.
[image: Mesh with highlighted edges]

How can I achieve this?